# multiple variable in get request of express

Tags: node.js, express

I got a problem on my express server

```
app.get('/callback/:nation/:username/?:permalink', function(req, res)
            {
                nationurl = req.params.nation;
                username = req.params.username;
                storypermalink = req.params.permalink;


                console.log("nation: "+nation);
                console.log("username: "+username);
                console.log("permalink: "+permalink);
            });
```

Beacause of the **/?:** it split the username and doesn't give my permalink :

```
nation: poneyclub
username: j
permalink: hondoe
```

Anybody have an idea ?

Comment: Could you please also post the URL with which you got this result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because `?` is a special character in Express routing algorithm. See [the documentation](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#routing) for details.

When you type URL Express treats everything after `?` character as a query. It should be in a format

```
?key1=value1&key2=value2&...&keyX=valueX
```

and it can be retrieved using `req.query`.

You can change this default behaviour using your own regular expression in route (again see [the documentation](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#routing) for details).